# how do I connect an ethernet module to a gps module using arduino

Tags: gps, arduino-uno, ethernet

First, I apologize for my mediocre English, hello I'm doing a project for college where I need to use a GY-GPS6MV2 gps module and using this module I need to use an enc28j60 ethernet module to save the gps data on a web page and later use a api. I was using the code below but I didn't get any data. Initially I used only the code related to the ethernet module so that later I could add the gps code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <UIPEthernet.h>

EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(80);
SoftwareSerial serial1(6, 7); // RX, TX
TinyGPS gps1;
void setup() {
  serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  uint8_t mac[6] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};

  IPAddress myIP(192, 168, 0, 200);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, myIP);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("GPS  Animal Tracker...");
}

void loop() {
   bool recebido = false;

  while (serial1.available()) {
    char cIn = serial1.read();
    recebido = gps1.encode(cIn);
  }
  if (recebido) {
    Serial.println("----------------------------------------");
    long latitude, longitude;
    unsigned long idadeInfo;
    gps1.get_position(&latitude, &longitude,  &idadeInfo);

    if (latitude != TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE) {
      Serial.print("Latitude: ");
      Serial.println(float(latitude) / 100000, 6);
    }

    if (longitude != TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE) {
      Serial.print("Longitude: ");
      Serial.println(float(longitude) / 100000, 6);
    }

    if (idadeInfo != TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE) {
      Serial.print("Idade da Informacao (ms): ");
      Serial.println(idadeInfo);
    }
    int ano;
      byte mes, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, centesimo;

      gps1.crack_datetime(&ano, &mes, &dia, &hora, &minuto, &segundo, &idadeInfo);

      Serial.print("Data (GMT): ");
      Serial.print(dia);
      Serial.print("/");
      Serial.print(mes);
      Serial.print("/");
      Serial.println(ano);

      Serial.print("Horario (GMT): ");
      Serial.print(hora);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(minuto);
      Serial.print(":");
   size_t size;

    if (EthernetClient client = server.available())
    {

      while ((size = client.available()) > 0)
      {
        uint8_t* msg = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
        size = client.read(msg, size);
        Serial.write(msg, size);
        free(msg);
      }
      client.println("<h1>ModuloEletronica</h1>");
      client.print("<h1>Latitude</h1>");
      //client.print((float(latitude) / 100000, 6));
      client.println();
      client.print ("<h1>Longitude</h1>");
      //client.print ((float(longitude) / 100000, 6));
      client.println();
      client.stop();
    }                                                                                                                                                              

      Serial.print(segundo);




  }
```

Comment: don't use malloc on a small MCU. and this is not the right way to receive a TCP communication with Arduino networking API. see some examples of the Ethernet library. first of all, read the request. browsers don't like to get a response before they finished to send the whole request.